# How to query a field inside an array from Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection in my project where I am trying to only fetch the relevant documents to my project.

My firestore looks like so:
[image: Firestore collection]

I am trying to only get the projects that contain the logged in user.
I only want to fetch the ones where one of the UID's in the users array matches the current users UID.

How do I filter the query to only get those in SwiftUI?

This is my ProjectRepository where I fetch the projects:

```
class ProjectRepository: ObservableObject
{
    var userId = ""
    
    private let fbAuth = FBAuth()
    
    private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    
    private let store = Firestore.firestore()
    
    @Published var projects: [Project] = []
    
    init()
    {
        fbAuth.$user
            .compactMap { user in
                user?.uid
            }
            .assign(to: \.userId, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        
        fbAuth.$user
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] _ in
                self?.get()
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
    // Retrieve projects from firebase
    func get()
    {
        store.collection(FirestoreKeys.CollectionPath.projects)
            .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
                
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error getting projects: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }
                
                self.projects = querySnapshot?.documents.compactMap{ document in
                    try? document.data(as: Project.self)
                } ?? []
            }
    }
    
    // Add projects to firebase
    func add(_ project: Project)
    {
        do {
            _ = try store.collection(FirestoreKeys.CollectionPath.projects).addDocument(from: project)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Unable to add card: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this support document [Querying and filtering data](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries#swift), you can simply write

```swift
let capitalCities = db.collection("cities").whereField("capital", isEqualTo: true)
```

to filter your data

Comment: Yes but what about in my case, where I want to get hold of the uid field inside the indexes of the users array. 

Here I have to get a field that is inside an index of an array which is inside a document inside a collection. 
I am not sure how to do it in this case.